# Why Is VS 2015 Add Service Reference Only Generating a Duplex Client?

Tags: wcf, service-reference

I'm adding a service reference using a WSDL and XSDs on a local drive.  I've done this many times in the past and the client class generated derives from System.ServiceModel.ClientBase.  For some reason, the only client class I get is derived from System.ServiceModel.DuplexClientBase.

I've tried unchecking "Allow generation of asynchronous operations" but I still only get one client class derived from DuplexClientBase.

How can a get a "normal" client derived from ClientBase?

I just tried one of the other WSDLs again and it generated the "normal" non-duplex client.  Is there something specified in the WSDL that forces a duplex client only?

Answer (score 0):

The WSDL defined one out of several operations with an output element only.  When I removed this operation and re-generated the proxy, it created a non-duplex client as expected.  Luckily, we do not need the "blahNbrChg" operation.

```
  <wsdl:portType name="BlahPortType">
<wsdl:operation name="blahNbrChg">
  <wsdl:output message="tns:blahNbrChgSoapOut"/>
  <wsdl:fault name="fault" message="tns:soapFault"/>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="xxxControl">
  <wsdl:input message="tns:xxxControlSoapIn"/>
  <wsdl:output message="tns:xxxControlSoapOut"/>
  <wsdl:fault name="fault" message="tns:soapFault"/>
</wsdl:operation>
```